# CGAffineTransformTranslate is Shrinking an image Instead of moving it

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform, quartz-core

I am trying to make a code that programmatically makes an image appear (eventually multiple images), and then translates the image. When I try to translate this image, the image doesn't move and instead shrinks. I have tested the translation code on another image that I pasted into the storyboard already and it worked.

Here is my code:

```
//this makes a zombie/person
UIImageView *ZombieView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(135 , 0, 50, 75)];
UIImage *Zombie=[UIImage imageNamed:@"free-vector-stick-figure-clip-art_105575_Stick_Figure_clip_art_hight.png"];
[ZombieView setImage:Zombie];
[self.view addSubview:ZombieView];

//This makes the Person move down until he is behind the railing
[UIView animateWithDuration:9.5
                    delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                    animations:^{
                    CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.ZombieView.transform, 0, 640);
                        ZombieView.transform=trans;
                    }
                     completion:nil];
```

I this is my header file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ZombieView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImage *Zombie;
```

I am sure the answer is simple, but I am new to coding in IOS so please keep this in mind. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your animation code, except that within the animation block you are referencing to the `ZombieView` that is connected to the one via `IBOutlet`, not the one you declare directly above the animation block.

And, you are using the transform of the `UIImageView` (`self.ZombieView`) connected through the `IBOutlet` to create a translate that you apply to the transform of the `UIImageView` (`ZombieView`) that is declared directly above the animation block.

Perhaps that is the reason.

Other than that, your animation should work.

***Addendum:***

I just remembered that using transforms when `autolayout` is enabled could produce unexpected results. So, in your case, if `self.ZombieView` is created on storyboard with that turned on and with you using that transform and apply it to the `ZombieView` transform, what you are experiencing can be explained.

So: within the animation block, change `self.ZombieView.transform` to `ZombieView.transform` and it should do as you expect.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

if you just want to translate this view, why dont you set a new frame to that image?

```
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectOffset(ZombieView.frame, 0, 600)
    [UIView animateWithDuration:9.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         ZombieView.frame = newFrame;
                    }];
```